# Random Failure of Simple Macro Designed to Hide Rows Based on Cell Value

Tags: excel, vba

My Macro is failing w/ seemingly no explanation. I'm thinking it could be a syntactical issue.

It is designed to hide/show certain rows based on a certain cell's (FacilityChoice) value. The value is input via Data Validation List.

It will work for a while , but sometimes the Debugger highlights one of my first two lines. I have been able to fix this simply by deleting and replacing the final character in each line.

Other times the Macro simply does not work & the debugger offers no feedback.

As described above, the failures I have observed fall into two categories:

1. an issue with Sub definition or the initial if not statement
2. an issue where no feedback is offered by the debugger

In scenario 1, I was able to fix the problem simply by deleting/rekeying the final character in the line.

I have been unable to successfully address scenario 2.

Please see code below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Application.Intersect(Range("FacilityChoice"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then

    'Gen Office Scenario
    
    If ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("SNA Tool").Range("FacilityChoice").Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("References").Range("E2") Then
    
        ActiveSheet.Rows(17 & ":" & 23).EntireRow.Hidden = False
        ActiveSheet.Rows(25).EntireRow.Hidden = False
        ActiveSheet.Rows(29 & ":" & 30).EntireRow.Hidden = False
        ActiveSheet.Rows(37 & ":" & 39).EntireRow.Hidden = False
        ActiveSheet.Rows(43 & ":" & 45).EntireRow.Hidden = False
        
    'POP Scenario
    
    ElseIf ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("SNA Tool").Range("FacilityChoice").Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("References").Range("E3") Then
    
        ActiveSheet.Rows(17 & ":" & 23).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        ActiveSheet.Rows(25).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        ActiveSheet.Rows(29 & ":" & 30).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        ActiveSheet.Rows(37 & ":" & 39).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        ActiveSheet.Rows(43 & ":" & 45).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        
    'Warehouse Scenario

    ElseIf ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("SNA Tool").Range("FacilityChoice").Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("References").Range("E4") Then
        ActiveSheet.Rows(17 & ":" & 23).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        ActiveSheet.Rows(25).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        ActiveSheet.Rows(29 & ":" & 30).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        ActiveSheet.Rows(37 & ":" & 39).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        ActiveSheet.Rows(43 & ":" & 45).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        
    'Rapid Scenario

    ElseIf ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("SNA Tool").Range("FacilityChoice").Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("References").Range("E5") Then
    
        ActiveSheet.Rows(17 & ":" & 23).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        ActiveSheet.Rows(25).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        ActiveSheet.Rows(29 & ":" & 30).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        ActiveSheet.Rows(37 & ":" & 39).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        ActiveSheet.Rows(43 & ":" & 45).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        
    End If

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Side note: `Range(Target.Address)` can/should be simplified to just `Target`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Select Case` and a little re-arrangement to simplify your code:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim wsRef As Worksheet, bHide As Boolean
    
    If Application.Intersect(Me.Range("FacilityChoice"), Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub 'no action
    
    Set wsRef = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("References")
    
    Select Case Me.Range("FacilityChoice").Value
        Case wsRef.Range("E2").Value
            bHide = False
        Case wsRef.Range("E3").Value, wsRef.Range("E4").Value, wsRef.Range("E5").Value
            bHide = True
        Case Else
            Exit Sub 'no action...
    End Select
    
    'set row visibility
    Me.Range("A17:A23,A25,A29:A30,A37:A39,A43:A45").EntireRow.Hidden = bHide
End Sub
```

Note in a worksheet event handler you can use `Me` to refer to the worksheet: it's safer than using `ActiveSheet`

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Tim - your solution is much more elegant. Much appreciated.                     However, I am now running into a new issue. The rows hidden are subject to several subtotal(109, range) formulae that are now totaling incorrectly when switching from a state w/ hidden rows back to the base case where wsref.range = References!E2. The issue is corrected when clicking into the formula and hitting enter. Do you know what might be causing this?

Comment: I don't know why that would be but you could always try adding something like  `Me.UsedRange.Calculate` at the end of the code to trigger a recalculation.

Comment: Tim - I tried to implement your fix in the below, but I may be thinking about this incorrectly. I figured that the subtotal rows would need to recalc in the event of any rows being hidden. Should the Recalc happen at the end of the sub outside of each case? :                                                                                                Select Case Me.Range("FacilityChoice").Value
        Case wsRef.Range("E2").Value
            bHide = False
            'triggers recalc of subtotals
            Me.Range("D31:Y31,D35:Y35,D41:Y41,D49:Y49,D52:Y52,D54:Y54").Calculate

Comment: I would put the recalc line right before the `End Sub`

Comment: Thanks for your help, Tim - unfortunately, I was unable to address the issue w/ that method. I ended up implementing a loop that sets each subtotal formula equal to itself which seems to work - however, it is pretty slow. I pasted it below if you're curious!                                                    
 Set Rng = Range("D31", Range("D31").End(xlToRight))
    
    For Each Cll In Rng
    
    Cll.Formula2R1C1 = Cll.Formula2R1C1
    
    Next Cll